# Bagging or Random Subspace Method for Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am reading a lot about the Random Forest regressor. I read about bagging (Bootstrap and aggregation) and random subspace. But I am not sure if the random forest regressor is just using bagging or bagging and random subspace method. Because in some articles, the random subspace method seems like an alternative to the bagging method.

Comment: I recently followed this videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvmPnGmCaIM&list=PLPOTBrypY74y0DviMOagKRUhDdk0JyM_r If you follow them it will give you a better understanding of RF

Comment: Thank you for sharing this video, but i dont understand why he is create a bootstrapp function and just use the implementation for the random forest?

Comment: Check the video of how to build a decision tree. If you start by there and follow the videos you should have a high knowledge of random forest and decision trees algorithms

Comment: Own answer in the SO thread [Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif/48239653#48239653) may be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern implementations do both, at least optionally.

sklearn has `max_features` and `bootstrap`.
ranger has `mtry` and `replace`/`sample.fraction`.
xgboost's random forest has `colsample_bynode` and `subsample`.
h2o has `mtries`/`col_sample_rate_per_tree` and `sample_rate` (and a couple modifiers).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If a want to use a random forest regressor with bagging i just have to select ´´´bootstrap=true´´´ and ´´´max_feature=auto´´´? What if i want to use both methods?

Comment: Correct (I might specify max_features=None just to be more explicit).  If you want both, still bootstrap=True, now max_features= basically anything else, depending on how small you want your subspace.  sqrt is the most common that I've seen, or a float if you want to do a hyperparameter search on different subspace sizes.